# Not able to generate dynamic position for text on canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to get dynamic point for text drawing using canvas in below example 
http://jsbin.com/kinebeza/1/

but ctx.fillText is not displaying anything when used without any number.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Starscream1984 says, the canvas default size is 300x150 so unless your document is small you're trying to draw the text beyond the canvas size.

Since you're dynamically setting the `x` value of fillText, you probably should dynamically resize the canvas also:

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];    
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

onResized("sanjana",100);           

function onResized(text,y){

    // resizing the canvas will also clear the canvas
    // so resize the canvas first

    var width_ = ($(document).width())/2;
    canvas.width=2*width_;

    // set the font size and measure the text width

    ctx.font = "60px Comic";
    var textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;

    // draw the text centered on the document

    ctx.fillText(text, width_ - textWidth/2, y);    

}
```

Comment: Why not use `ctx.textAlign = 'center'` instead of measure the text width manually?

Comment: @Ken ... that works too.  But, I assume calculating the startingX will be useful for subsequent drawing on the canvas.  (I assume this lonely text won't be the only thing drawn on the canvas).

Comment: @markE : As had just started learning jquery your solution helps a lot. I am having one more doubt in the code, why to use index 0 while creating canvas object like var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];

Comment: When you do $("#myCanvas) you're getting a collection of all elements with id=myCanvas (yes, there should be only 1 but jquery still returns a collection).  So [0] will get a single element from the collection.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things here:

The jQuery script is not loading correctly (in the jsBin). You can put jQuery in header or configurate jsbin load your script after jQuery has been loaded.

You should define a bitmap size for the canvas element using its width and height attributes (setting additional width/height using styles is not necessary and should be avoided for canvas elements).

If not canvas default to 300x150. As you are using document in your query as basis for the width, text position would be very off in most cases.

You can set

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

if you want the canvas to fill the client window. Attach a window.onresize

```
$(window).on('resize, ...)
```

to update the sizes in case client window changes size.

Then use `canvas.width` as basis for text placement:

```
var width_ = canvas.width * 0.5;
```

To center text also set canvas text alignment to center

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
```

**[Working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kinebeza/3/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

This is due to canvas being funny with it's width and height settings, to get it to play as you expect, set the width and height directly on the element and also in styles:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=500 height=240 style='width:500px;height:240px'></canvas>
```

Comment: +1, yep, the canvas was too small to display the text as the dynamically computed `x`